# KiCad schematic editor "frozen"; nothing can be selected

Tags: kicad, debugging

While working on my circuit, I did a test gerber file export to JLC PCB to see how much it would cost. Coming back, and **now I can no longer select ANY footprint/PCB route/copper pad/element.** Right-click still works, and I can route tracks, but can't select anything. What just happened? **How can we fix this issue?**

My window looks like this:

[image: Windows page]

Note: If I select a component/connection in the schematic window, it does select it in the schematic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have turned off the selection filter. You need to select "All items" if you want to be able to select things.

[image]